# Consistent formula in Cell

Tags: excel

In Excel, I want to make consistant formula in a cell.

```
  | A     | B  |C
--|-------|----|----------------------------------------
1 | Date1 | 12 |=B1
2 | Date1 | 45 |=B2+B1
3 | Date1 | 20 |=SUMIF(A1:A100, A3, B1:B100)
4 | Date2 | 10 |=B4
5 | Date2 |  5 |=B4+B5
6 | Date2 | 28 |=B4+B5+B6
7 | Date2 | 88 |=SUMIF(A1:A100, A7, B1:B100)
```

I used different formulas in cell `C` for each row. How to make `Consistent Formula` in Cell `C`?

> Is it possible to select particular range in `SUMIF` function? e.g. Instead of **SUMIF(A1:A100, A7, B1:B100)**, I want **SUMIF(A1:A100, A7, B4:B7)**

Comment: What you are trying to accomplish is not very clear. I admire the effort you paid in arranging your question to make it understandable, but still it is not clear what it is that you want to do

Comment: I want to make single formula in cell `C` for each row...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This single formula will do it

```
=SUMIFS($B$1:B1,$A$1:A1,A1)
```

Enter in `C1`, copy down as far as required.

Note the `$`'s.  These anchor the Criteria Range and Sum Range at row 1.  When the formula is copied down these ranges will expand down to the row the formula is in.

Comment: It is working fine as expected...  Is `B4:B7` instead of `$B$1:B7` possible?

Comment: Why would it be necassary? The `SUMIFS` part will exclude `B1:B3` for the sum anyway. (this formula produces the same results as your sample data)

Comment: Yes, thats fine... Just I interested to know whether it is possible or not? Instead of looking from the First row (referenced row) to current row, check only particular range... Anyway, thanks for your help :)